# confused definition in C# class variables

Tags: c#

the following is in a c# code (the whole project is too large) with a new format which I have never seen before, I don't know how FieldOffset could be placed before the variable definition!
I am trying to use this struct to assign a float value=55 to **Field2Float**, then I surprisingly find
**Field2Int** is also automatically assigned with a value 1113325568, how does this happen? since I am translating this code to python, how should I do the same thing in python? thanks

```
  public class LutG1Record
    {
        /// <summary>Instruction value.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)] public byte Instruction;
        /// <summary>First field value split into 3 bytes.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(1)] private byte field1b0;
        [FieldOffset(2)] private byte field1b1;
        [FieldOffset(3)] private byte field1b2;
        /// <summary>Instruction combined with Field1 in a 32-bit int.</summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)] private int InstructionAndField1;
        /// <summary>Second field value is an integer (use Field2Float to store a float).</summary>
        [FieldOffset(4)] public int Field2Int;
        /// <summary>Second field value is a float (use Field2Int to store an int).</summary>
        [FieldOffset(4)] public float Field2Float;
        /// <summary>
        /// This represents a 24 bit uint field.
        /// </summary>
```

**update:** for float value = 55.0, if i use

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(record.Field2Float);
var result = string.Format("0x{0:x}{1:x}{2:x}{3:x}", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

I could get `result = 0x005c42`
then for another value 1113325568 it is `425c0000`
so looks both Field2Float and Field2Int just read the same location value?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `C#-4.0`? There's nothing in the code you've posted that's specific to version 4.0 of C#.

Comment: Why are you using `FieldOffset` in the first place? Is this for interop?

Comment: To use specific struct layouts in Python you should read this: https://pymotw.com/2/struct/

Comment: @Dai, this is I am confused about, I have never seen this format, it is a struct format for class member? only C# has this format?

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? Also, please answer my question about the purpose of `LutG1Record`. Is this for interop or not? And are you familiar with the concept of struct-packing?

Comment: @Dai, the purpose of LutG1Record is to define a struct to interpret a text input file, and convert to a fixed format, do CRC and send to the controller hardware. I am not aware of  struct-packing, I thought Field2Float and Field2Int are both in the same memory location with different length, but hard to explain 55 & 1113325568, whatever I play woth bits, I  could not get convertion between 55 & 1113325568

Comment: @adameye2020 See [LayoutKind Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.8) and in particular the `Explicit` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how FieldOffset could be placed before the variable definition!

`FieldOffset` is an attribute, and the full name of the class is `FieldOffsetAttribute`. This specific attribute can be placed before (or "on") fields.

> how does this happen?

This specific attribute instructs the compiler to generate the fields "on top of each other", so `Field2Int` and `Field2Float` resolve to the same memory locations, with the same size (both `int` and `float` have the same size).

Though you're missing the important second half of these kinds of declarations, using a `struct` and declaring it with `StructLayout`, otherwise the compiler is still more or less free to mangle your class definition up.

A quick Google search shows `struct.pack` can be used to convert `float` to `int` and back byte-wise in Python, which is what this sample is doing. By the way, this is not the only way to do this in C#, you can simply reinterpret a pointer to `int*` into a pointer to `float*` and then dereference it, much like in C.